# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp working horizontally

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I try to make the UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp work horizontally so, I rotate the view where the animation is applied. But the didn't work, the animation stay from the bottom to the top. Any idea?

```
first = [[PDFPortraitView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 960, 768) andCurrentPage:currentPage];
    container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-96, 140, 960, 768)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * (0.5));
    [self.view addSubview:container];
    [container addSubview:first];


    second = [[PDFPortraitView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 960, 768) andCurrentPage:currentPage];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5f];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:container cache:NO];
    [first removeFromSuperview];
    [container addSubview:second];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a 90 degree rotation to your view's superview's transform. That should transform your view's coordinate space, so a curl transition applied to the child view should curl in rotated coordinates.

You might have to create multiple views to keep your content from being rotated:

outer view, rotated 90 degrees.

middle view - this is the view that gets the curl transition

```
   inner view, rotated -90 degrees, and containing your actual content.
```

I haven't tried it, but that should work.

Note that the view you switch to will have to be a middle view/inner view combo.